# MYSQL can't add a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I really can't get a clue, as everything seems to be ok. This is the command I'm trying:

```
ALTER TABLE dashboard ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (app_name, app_parent, client)
REFERENCES apps(app_name, app_parent, client) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

This is the error I get:

```
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Using an explicit name for the FK doesn't help. This is the *referenced* table:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS IN apps;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default    | Extra |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| app_name   | varchar(20)      | NO   | PRI |            |       |
| app_parent | varchar(20)      | NO   | PRI |            |       |
| client     | varchar(12)      | NO   | PRI | NULL       |       |
| order_idx  | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | 100        |       |
...
```

And this is the *referencing* table:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS IN dashboard;
+------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| app_name   | varchar(20)          | NO   |     |         |       |
| app_parent | varchar(20)          | NO   |     |         |       |
| client     | varchar(12)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| widget     | varchar(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
...
```

Both tables have InnoDB as the engine. And this is the (rather laconic) clue I'm getting from `SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS`:

```
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2014-06-20 11:49:57 10ec Error in foreign key constraint of table the_db/#sql-128c_2:
FOREIGN KEY (app_name, app_parent, client)
REFERENCES apps(app_name, app_parent, client) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
for correct foreign key definition.
```

What does it mean it doesn't find an index on `apps`? I'm referencing primary keys! And the types are clearly the same.

**EDIT**: this is the CREATE command for apps:

```
CREATE TABLE `apps` (
  `app_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `app_parent` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `client` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `order_idx` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '100',
  ...,
  PRIMARY KEY (`app_name`,`app_parent`,`client`),
  KEY `client` (`client`),
  CONSTRAINT `apps_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client`) REFERENCES `clients` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `apps_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`app_name`, `app_parent`) REFERENCES `app_list` (`name`, `parent`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I must add that I actually managed to create a foreign key on the same columns on another table:

```
mysql> SHOW COLUMNS IN user_apps;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| app_name   | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| app_parent | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| username   | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| client     | varchar(12) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
...
```

Here, `app_name`, `app_parent` and `client` reference to the same named columns in `apps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the sneakiest of the mistakes: the problem was the default character set, which is latin1 for apps and utf8 for dashboard.

This solved my problem:

```
ALTER TABLE dashboard CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You better have posted output of

```
show create table apps
```

I am not sure if the referenced parent columns are indexed.
But for them to be eligible for referring from other child tables, they *MUST* have *`INDEXed`*

As per documentation on `foreign key` constraints:

> REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)

Define an `INDEX`es on columns `app_name, app_parent, client` of `apps` table.

If not already defined, then use following command:

```
ALTER TABLE apps 
   ADD INDEX ix_app_name( app_name )
 , ADD INDEX ix_app_parent( app_parent )
 , ADD INDEX ix_app_client( client )
```

And other primary constraints are that,

- The child column definition MUST match with that of parent column.
- Database `ENGINE` type must be same.

**Refer to**:

- [**MySQL ALTER TABLE Syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html)
- [**MySQL Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
>       [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
>       REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
>       [ON DELETE reference_option]
>       [ON UPDATE reference_option]
>
> reference_option:
>       RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION

Comment: I edited my question with the create command for the referenced table. Maybe `SHOW INDEXES IN apps` could be helpful too?

Comment: You have a combo primary key and a single key on client in parent. You should have indexes on each of the columns as like on client column.

Comment: I don't think it's the point. As I said, I've already managed (a while ago) to add a similar constraint on another table. And this constraint produces the exact same error: `ALTER TABLE dashboard ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (client) REFERENCES clients(name) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;`. On `clients`, `name` is the only primary key.

Comment: It succeeded because `clients.name` has a `KEY` aka `INDEX` defined on it.

Comment: Please see the highlighted `REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)` syntax. Each column to be referred MUST BE indexed.

Comment: You misunderstood: the reference to `clients` it did *not* succeed. I added the indexes, but to no avail: I still get the error 1215.